# Same boolean calculation giving 2 different results in 2 different examples. Why?

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain why the boolean (`"a" in window`) throws **true** in 1st example and **false** in 2nd example?

I have actually no clue what is this `in` and how is this boolean getting calculated?

**1st Example:**

```js
if ("a" in window) {
  var a = 1;
}
console.log(a);
```

**2nd Example:**

```js
console.log("a" in window);
```

Comment: `var` on the top level creates a property on `window` (and `var`s are hoisted as well)

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-hoisting-dfa84512dd28

Comment: @bambam This is not a duplicate. The answer is hoisting, and that is not given in the marked duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CertainPerformance mentioned, your ***`var` gets [hoisted](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript) to top & becomes accessible globally***, it's a normal behaviour in JavaScript. FYI, they have *introduced a `let` keyword for a block scope in ES6*.

So you can observe, both the statements are returning `boolean`s, but in your `if` condition, you are assigning a value 1 to the variable `a`, *therefore it returns the same & the later one directly returns a boolean*.

> In short, ***in the first condition, you are printing a variable value***, whereas ***in second one, you are printing the result of a condition***.

---

If you don't want them to be hoisted in ES5, you can effectively use **[IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)s** to limit the scope as follows -

```js
if (true) {
  (function() {
      var a = 1;
      console.log('in block, a = ' + a);    // returns 1
  })();    // IIFE
}
console.log(a);    // inaccessible here, returns an error
```

Similarly in ES6 -

```js
if (true) {
  let a = 1;       // let keyword
  console.log('in block, a = ' + a);    // returns 1
}
console.log(a);    // inaccessible here, returns an error
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one returns true because the variable(`a`) declared gets `hoisted` and the if condition `returns true`. If the variable name is changed you will get undefined as the if condition will now `return false`

[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

```js
if ("a" in window) { 
var t = 1;
}
console.log(t);
```